# 'this' pointer, inheriting functions of super class in subclass using 'this' pointer

Tags: c++, inheritance, subclass, this-pointer

Hi i am trying to understand how to use the 'this' pointer. Now i wrote a sample program which uses a class Image which is a subclass of a class BMP. Now the functions TellWidth and TellHeight are declared in the BMP class. Now the compiler gives me an error which says that the TellWidth function does not exist in Image. But as Image is a subclass of BMP shouldnt it inherit the functions in BMP. 
How do i resolve this

```
void Image :: invertcolors()
{
    int x;
    int y;

    int width  =(*this).TellWidth();
    int height = (*this)->TellHeight();

    for(x=0,x<=height-1;x++){
        for(y=0,y<=width-1;y++){
            (*this)(x,y)->Red = (255 - (*this)(x,y)->Red);
            (*this)(x,y)->Blue = (255 - (*this)(x,y)->Blue);
            (*this)(x,y)->Green = (255 - (*this)(x,y)->Green);

        }
    }
    delete width;
    delete height;
}
```

Image

```
class Image : public BMP  
{
public:

    void invertcolors();

    void flipleft();
    void adjustbrightness(int r, int g, int b) ;

};
```

This class is too big to post here, here is a relavent excerpt

```
class BMP {
private:
   int Width;
   int Height;
public:
   int TellBitDepth(void) const;
   int TellWidth(void) const;
   int TellHeight(void) const;
};
```

Comment: Please post the parts of the header file(s) that declare the classes Image and BMP. Include the `class` declarations themselves, and the declaration(s) for `invertcolors`, `TellWidth`, and `TellHeight`.  Also include any kind of data declaration(s) for representing the bitmap data (e.g., arrays), and/or field declarations named `x` and `y` if they happen to exist (see my answer below.) You can probably delete everything else in the header files, at least for now.

Comment: Please also include the definitions of any fields or methods named `Red`, `Green`, or `Blue`.

Comment: It compiles fine for me if I remove the irrelevant Red/Green/Blue part and fix the obvious error with `(*this)->`. Maybe you've got the problem with linking, not compiling? Perhaps these functions either aren't defined or their units aren't included in the linking process?

Comment: Also, it is very unlikely, but maybe you're using some weird compiler that doesn't like the `(void)` formal argument list for those functions? It is perfectly valid, but rarely used in C++, usually it's just `()`.

Answer (score 3):

`TellWidth()` is most likely declared as `private` (or has no accessor modifier) in the `BMP` class. It needs to be `protected` or `public` for the `Image` class to be able to access it, and it needs to be also `virtual`, if you want to be able to override it in the `Image` class.

And the proper `this` usage is like this:

```
int width = this->TellWidth();
int height = this->TellHeight();
```

Read [`this`](http://www.codersource.net/c/c-tutorials/c-tutorial-this-pointer.aspx) for a quick tutorial on `this`.

Comment: TellWidth() is public. And when u use the usage you have mentioned the compiler tells me that class Image has no member names TellWidth.

Answer (score 1):

One point about `this`: you rarely need to mention it explicitly. The usual exception is when you need to pass it into a non-member function (which doesn't seem to be the case here.)

When you're inside of a class member function, `this->field` can be accessed simply as `field`, and `this->function(x)` can be invoked as `function(x)`.

Here are some comments on your code. I hope they're helpful.

```
void Image :: invertcolors()
{
    // Don't define these here; that's old C-style code. Declare them where
    // they're needed (in the loop: for (int x=0...)
    int x;
    int y;

    // Change the lines below to
    // int width  = TellWidth();
    // int height = TellHeight();
    //    (*this).TellWidth() should work, but is redundant;
    //    (*this)->TellHeight() should probably *not* work, as once you've
    //    dereferenced *this, you're dealing with an object instance, not a
    //    pointer. (There are ways to make (*this)->that() do something useful,
    //    but you're probably not trying something like that.)
    int width  =(*this).TellWidth();
    int height = (*this)->TellHeight();

    for(x=0,x<=height-1;x++){
        for(y=0,y<=width-1;y++){
            // After locating the BMP class through google (see Edit 2),
            // I've confirmed that (*this)(x,y) is invoking a (int,int) operator
            // on the BMP class. It wasn't obvious that this operator 
            // was defined; it would have been helpful if you'd posted
            // that part of the header file.
            (*this)(x,y)->Red = (255 - (*this)(x,y)->Red);
            (*this)(x,y)->Blue = (255 - (*this)(x,y)->Blue);
            (*this)(x,y)->Green = (255 - (*this)(x,y)->Green);

        }
    }
    // These are int values. They can't be deleted, nor do they need to be.
    // I'm sure the compiler has told you the same thing, though perhaps not
    // in the same way.
    delete width;
    delete height;
}
```

**EDIT**: Looks like there's someone else taking the [same course](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824596/minor-image-differences-in-image-manipulation-program) as the OP. The example presented there makes it clearer that Image is supposed to have some sort of array accessor, which may explain what `(*this)(x,y)->Red = (255 - (*this)(x,y)->Red)` was intended to achieve.

**EDIT 2**:  [Here's the source](http://easybmp.sourceforge.net/download.html) for the original BMP class.

Answer (score 0):

class Image is defined as

```
class Image : public BMP  
{
public:

    void invertcolors();

    void flipleft();
    void adjustbrightness(int r, int g, int b) ;

};
```

Comment: What is class `BMP` defined as?

Comment: class BMP{ private   

int Width;

   int Height;
  
public:

   int TellBitDepth(void) const;
   int TellWidth(void) const;
   int TellHeight(void) const;
   };

This is part of the class the other i wrote earlier is too big to post

Comment: Please post the code as edits to your question, not as answers or comments.