# Minor image differences in image manipulation program

Tags: c++, image, pixel

I've implemented a method that takes an input image and flips it around a vertical line through the center and saves it to an output image file. So whats on the left becomes on the right and vice versa. The image looks great and looks like it flipped perfectly. However, we are given the actual flipped image file that its supposed to look like, and I used the diff utility in terminal to compare the two, and it states that there are indeed differences. Using a program called Kaliedoscope, I was able to find out the difference:there are a handful of pixels that for some reason are colored differently than they should be. Not sure why it is. My code doesnt even manipulate RGB values.

Comment: Are you saving the images into a lossy format, such as .jpg, before doing the comparison?

Comment: How different are these pixels? Does it look right to the human eye, but there is a very tiny actual difference in the pixels' colour? Or can you tell they are different?

Comment: What sample images are you comparing to? Is it possible that when they were flipped, some sort of smoothing algorithm was applied—bilinear or bicubic, for example? That would alter the color values of individual pixels slightly as far as a computer is concerned, but imperceptibly to a human eye.

Comment: I'm saving them as bmp's. The difference was impossible to see until I used an image comparison program..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What image format did you save as? If you used a lossy compression, such as JPEG, then the image colours will always be slightly different, as they have been re-compressed. You should use a non-lossy format such as PNG.

You should also not use 'diff' to look at images. I don't know what Kaleidoscope is, but the ImageMagick 'compare' utility is good for looking at the difference between two images. 'diff' will almost always tell you there is a difference between two images, even if they are identical and you used a non-lossy format, due to the fact that when you recompressed it, it might use a different compression technique.

Also, you say you were given the flipped image file (assuming this is a homework thing). In that case, it's possible that the person who generated that file made the mistake (e.g., using a lossy compression). I would not worry about minor pixel differences in that case.

Comment: OK well if you are saving it as a BMP then it should be non-lossy (like PNG). Assuming there is nothing wrong with yours, there could still be a problem in either the provided solution, or this Kaleidoscope program. If you have [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) installed, try using `convert -flop original.bmp expected.bmp`, which will create the expected output image, and test against that. Use ImageMagick's "compare" program to test the difference.

Answer (score 0):

If your function works well, it should be its own inverse (as a necessary condition, although not enough to prove correctness).

Check if

```
a == flipleft(flipleft(a))
```

What if you trusted third party testing software has a bug?

HTH!

**Edit**

Also check the vertical center of the image, to be sure that when the number of horizontal pixels is even you are swapping the two in the middle.

Comment: @mohabitar just apply your method again to the resulting image. It should return the original one once applied two times in a row

Comment: It means if you have an Image object 'a', and you call your 'flipleft' function on it twice, you should end up with an image which is equal. A few caveats: Firstly, you have defined it as a method so it's probably more like a == a->flipleft()->flipleft(). Secondly, it assumes that == compares the images, which would mean you'd have to write your own == operator. Instead, you should just manually compare the pixels in both images to see if they are all the same.

Comment: @mohabitar If you found them to be the same, it might suggest (but wouldn't confirm) that your software is working, and the other person who gave you the test solution made a (small) mistake. If you apply it twice and it doesn't match, then there is obviously a mistake in your code.

Comment: @mohabitar Because by doing this you may identify the logic that goes underneath. And do it for images on one channel only (R, G or B) to explore more.

Comment: @mgiuca Thanks for the above comments. I'm obviously out the c++ circuit. Just trying to help with the image part.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be anything obviously wrong with your code.

Since you have a reference image, you can tell the precise pixel positions where there is a difference.  I suggest that you step through your program with a debugger (gdb if you're a Linux user, or Visual Studio if that's what floats your boat) and put breakpoints in the inner loop of your code at the problem positions.  Using those breakpoints, look for the first point in the program where the problem manifests itself.  This will help you find the cause.

Working with smaller images (something that you can print to the command-line at each iteration, for example 8x8 pixels) may save you some time when debugging.

It may be good to post images -- your result and the expected reference.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code so that you read the input image into an `Image` and then write it into an output file (without reversal) and compare the input file to the output file.

**If they do not match** then either the file->Image->file process is corrupting the data (perhaps with a pixel member that is the wrong size, leading to roundoff or use of uninitialized memory) or the comparator (e.g. Kaleidoscope) is wrong, and you can test by just copying the input file and comparing.

**If they do match** then either your reversal procedure is wrong (which seems unlikely) or the reference file (which the output "is supposed to look like") is wrong, and you can test by altering the code to read in the reference file as well, and report the first disagreement-- that is, construct three `Images`, Before (read from the input file), After (which will be written to the output file) and Reference (which was read from the reference file), then iterate over x and y, comparing After(x,y) to Reference(x,y). As soon as you find a disagreement, see which one matches Before(width-x-1, y); if Reference matches then your reversal routine is wrong, and if After matches then the reference file is wrong (and you can point to a pixel that proves it).